# Conditional where clause in Oracle SQL query is not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a select on Oracle DB with this condition but it is not working.

```
LocalDateTime endDate = null;
```

Table POST

```
ID NUMBER
DATE_END TIMESTAMP(6)
```

```
select p.id from post p where (:endDate is null or p.date_end < :endDate);
```

but when `endDate` is null I got the error

```
ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER.
```

Please help

Comment: "LocalDateTime endDate = null;" doesn't look like SQL to me.  What is the client that's trying to select?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the (Java?) code from which you are calling the query. The error is almost certainly from how you are passing the bind variable to the query as the query will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to transform the Date in String, and in the select do this
and (:endDate is null or pl.date_end <= TO_DATE(:endDate , 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MI:SS'))

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select p.id
  from post p
 where (to_date(:endDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') is null
    or p.date_end < to_date(:endDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

Comment: Its a `TIMESTAMP` not a `DATE` so this answer will, at best, give different answers to expected as it strips the time component.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Setup

```
create table test (
DATE_END TIMESTAMP);

insert into test values (timestamp  '2009-12-26 22:22:22.123456');
insert into test values (timestamp  '2009-12-26 22:22:22.123458');
```

This query simulates your exception

```
select * from test where DATE_END > 1;
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER
```

So you most probably use some incorrect `set` method for the bind variable.

Anyway `setTimestamp` works with JDBC Driver `12.1.0.2.0` on `18 XE`

```
def stmt = con.prepareStatement("select DATE_END from test where ? is null or DATE_END > ?")
stmt.setTimestamp(1,null)
stmt.setTimestamp(2,null)

def rs = stmt.executeQuery()
while(rs.next())
 {
   println "ts= ${rs.getTimestamp(1)}"
 }
```

returns both rows

```
ts= 2009-12-26 22:22:22.123456 
ts= 2009-12-26 22:22:22.123458
```

While is you pass a real timestamp you get a limited result

```
def ts = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf('2009-12-26 22:22:22.123457')

def stmt = con.prepareStatement("select DATE_END from test where ? is null or DATE_END > ?")
stmt.setTimestamp(1,ts)
stmt.setTimestamp(2,ts)
...

ts= 2009-12-26 22:22:22.123458
```